# Jmeter SOAP/ XML-RPC request default URL

Tags: soap, jmeter

I am trying to test web service for my project. The Web service accepts a SOAP request and gives appropriate response.

In JMeter I have chosen SOAP/ XML-RPC request. It works completely fine for me and gives me correct response. However, I have more than 100s of web services in my scope of testing and I have to test them in different environments. It is very cumbersome work to change the URL value from the SOAP/ XML-RPC sample to point it to different env. Do we have something like HTTP Request Default for SOAP/XML-RPC requests?

I have also tried a bean shell sampler where I am setting the value of a variable and then retrieve it in the SOAP sampler URL parameter. However it did not work for me. Below is the code.

Bean Shell sampler code:
vars.put("baseURL","http://localhost:9191/ws/soap");

SOAP/ XML-RPS Sampler URL value:
${__BeanShell(vars.get("baseURL"))}

Any suggestions? I read in JMeter docs that this can be done via http sampler, however, I want to avoid using the same if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JMeter Properties to set base url like:

- in *user.properties* file (under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) add one line per property:

  ```
  baseURL=http://localhost:9191/ws/soap
  ```
- alternatively you can pass the property via -J command line key as:

  ```
  jmeter -JbaseURL=http://localhost:9191/ws/soap -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl
  ```

Refer the defined property in your test plan using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

```
${__P(baseURL,)}
```

You can even provide the default value, i.e. if the property is not set via user.properties file or command-line argument - default value will be used:

```
${__P(baseURL,http://localhost:9191/ws/soap)}
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting, overriding and using them.

Comment: It worked. Thanks Dimitri. I wonder why it dint work with the Bean Shell code I wrote above. Have I made any mistake?

Comment: Hi Dmitri, what do you think of my solution below ? Do you agree with my comment ?

Comment: @Abhiram: I need to see your testplan (at least screenshot) and jmeter.log file to be able to tell for sure what's wrong

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK I agree with your solution, but I would mention that HTTP Header Manager will be required in that case. Also it won't work for e.g. multiple thread groups

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using SOAP/XML-RPC in favor of pure Http Sampler.
Use the "Templates..." (menu) > Building a SOAP Webservice Test Plan:

[image]

[image]

This way you can use HTTP Request Default if you want.

But note from what you describe, using a CSV Data Set Config would allow you to variabilize the URL.

Comment: Thanks UBIK LOAD PACK

Comment: Hi, IMHO, you accepted the wrong answer as it is not a long term solution. You should really follow my advice and at least if you don't accept the long term solution to avoid misleading users. I think @dmitri-t agrees with my comment :-)

Comment: I tried with both the options and it both worked for me. I wanted to mark both of them as solutions however when I mark one as solution the other one is unmarked.
Also, since I have to run the scripts form different machines for diff env. I thought updating the properties file option for once might be better option than CSV file.
You and Dimitri both are experts in JMeter as compared to me and your opinions will always be valuable for me. I have no intention to mislead anyone.

Comment: no problem, reading further your question and dmitri answer , I see that both answers are ok, but I want to highlight that you should use Http Sampler instead of Soap / Xml rpc sampler.